Teams chatbot permission denied when test in microsoft teams
I have a teams bot powered by Azure AI service, when I test the bot in VS code Test Tool () I am able to chat with it.
But, when  I try to Debug in Teams Chrome (), I get:
{
  error: {
    code: 'PermissionDenied',
    message: 'Principal does not have access to API/Operation.'
  }
}

I gave the permission Cognitive Services OpenAI Contributor to my personal user on my Azure AI services resource and also to the App registration of my bot created when I ran for the first time the debug in Teams option.
I am clueless about the missing permission.

Your Azure Account must have Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write permissions, such as User Access Administrator or Owner.
To assign specific custom roles of OpenAI operations you should be able to lookup the actions by searching OpenAI on this page.  Try regenerating the API key for your Azure OpenAI resource in the Azure portal and see if that helps.
